# BigQuery Pagination

Tags: google-bigquery

How to do pagination using BigQuery ,when using javascript

First I send request:

```
var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
    'projectId': project_id,
    'timeoutMs': '30000',
    'query': query,
    'maxResults' : 50,
    'pageToken': pageToken
   });
```

This query will return me first 50 results and then how can i retrieve next 50 results.I want to do pagination dynamically using javascript and Bigquery.

query:

```
SELECT year, month,day,state,mother_age, AVG(weight_pounds) as AvgWeight FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] Group EACH By year, month,day,state, mother_age
```

This is the query that i am using.

Comment: I followed the documentation.Can anyone give me proper code example.I want dynamic pagination and not whole data at a time.When user click on particular page number in a data grid,it should return that page number results only and not all the results.I have idea that whenever we run query then it will create a temporary dataset and table and by using that dataset and table we will move forward to implement paginnation.thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TableData.list works, or alternately you can use `jobs.getQueryResults()`, which is usually the preferred way to get query results (since it can also wait for the query to complete).

You should use the page token returned from the original query response or the previous `jobs.getQueryResults()` call to iterate through pages. This is generally more efficient and reliable than using index-based pagination.

I don't have a javascript example, but here is an example using python that should be relatively easy to adapt:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

def run_query(http, service, project_id, query, response_handler,
              timeout=30*1000, max_results=1024):
  query_request = {
      'query': query,
      'timeoutMs': timeout,
      'maxResults': max_results}
  print 'Running query "%s"' % (query,)
  response = service.jobs().query(projectId=project_id,
      body=query_request).execute(http)
  job_ref = response['jobReference']

  get_results_request = {
      'projectId': project_id,
      'jobId': job_ref['jobId'],
      'timeoutMs': timeout,
      'maxResults': max_results}

  while True:
    print 'Response %s' % (response,)
    page_token = response.get('pageToken', None)
    query_complete = response['jobComplete']
    if query_complete:
      response_handler(response)
      if page_token is None:
        # Our work is done, query is done and there are no more
        # results to read.
        break;
    # Set the page token so that we know where to start reading from.
    get_results_request['pageToken'] = page_token
    # Apply a python trick here to turn the get_results_request dict
    # into method arguments.
    response = service.jobs().getQueryResults(
        **get_results_request).execute(http)

def print_results(results):
  fields = results['schema']['fields']
  rows = results['rows']
  for row in rows:
    for i in xrange(0, len(fields)):
      cell = row['f'][i]
      field = fields[i]
      print "%s: %s " % (field['name'], cell['v']),
    print ''

def run(http, query):
  service = build('bigquery', 'v2')
  project_id = '#Your Project Here#'
  run_query(http, service, project_id, query, print_results,
           timeout=1)
```

Comment: I followed the documentation.Can anyone give me proper code example.I want dynamic pagination and not whole data at a time.When user click on particular page number in a data grid,it should return that page number results only and not all the results.I have idea that whenever we run query then it will create a temporary dataset and table and by using that dataset and table we will move forward to implement paginnation.thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've added a code sample in python. I realize you're working in js but hopefully this is easy enough to adapt.

Comment: Thats a good example.Thanks for your help.Actually i want to use it with jquery jqgrid.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Once the query has run, all results will be saved to a temporary table (or permanent, if you have set the respective flag).

You can read these results with [`tabledata.list`](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list). Notice that it offers an `startIndex` argument, so you can jump to any arbitrary page too, not only to the next one.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list

Comment: I followed the documentation.Can anyone give me proper code example.I want dynamic pagination and not whole data at a time.When user click on particular page number in a data grid,it should return that page number results only and not all the results.I have idea that whenever we run query then it will create a temporary dataset and table and by using that dataset and table we will move forward to implement paginnation.thanks for your reply. –